# $A,B$ are orthogonal projections and $\|Ax\|^2+\|Bx\|^2=\|x\|^2$ show $A+B=I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products, projection-matrices

**Here is the problem**: $A,B:\mathbb{C}^n\to\mathbb{C}^n$ are two orthogonal projections satisfying for any $x\in\mathbb{C}^n$, $$\|Ax\|^2+\|Bx\|^2=\|x\|^2$$ Show that $A+B=I$.

---

I know that $\|Ax\|^2+\|Bx\|^2=\|x\|^2$ tells that $(Ax,Ax)+(Bx,Bx)=(x,x)$.

Since $$\|(A+B)x\|^2=((A+B)x,(A+B)x)$$$$=(Ax,Ax)+(Bx,Bx)+(Ax,Bx)+(Bx,Ax)$$$$=(x,x)+(Ax,Bx)+(Bx,Ax)$$

It remian to show that $(Ax,Bx)+(Bx,Ax)=0$, but I am not sure how to show it.

Please help, thanks a lot!

Comment: Even if you show $\lVert (A+B) x \rVert = \lVert x \rVert$, it would only mean that $A+B$ is an isometry. Perhaps you want to show that $Im(A)  \oplus Im(B) = \mathbb{C}^n$?

Comment: $\|Ax\|^2+\|Bx\|^2=\|x\|^2=\|Ax+(I-A)x\|^2=\|Ax\|^2+\|(I-A)x\|^2$. Therefore, $\|Bx\|^2=\|(I-A)x\|^2$ for all $x$. Now, assume $y\in Range(B)\setminus Range(I-A)$. Then $By=y$, but $\|(I-A)y\|^2<\|(I-A)y\|^2+\|Ay\|^2=\|y\|^2$, since $Ay\neq 0$, contradiction. Therefore $Range(I-A)\supset Range(B)$. The reverse inclusion follows the same way. Therefore, $B=I-A$.

Comment: And that $Im(A)$ and $Im(B)$ are orthogonal subspaces.

Comment: @totoro Kindly write your comment as an answer as you have provided a correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

Let me state two hints and one proposal:

- One has $\,\|Ax\|^2=(Ax,x)\,$ by hypothesis.
- What does $\,(Tx,x)=0\;\forall x\in\mathbb C^n\,$ imply for $T$?
  (The conclusion **would not hold** when working in $\mathbb R^n$!)
- Please use the command "\|" to produce nice(-r) norm delimiters,
  cf $\,\|\,$ versus $\,||$.